# How to turn this sum into a continuous function when it contains$\sqrt{\frac{1}{\Delta t}}$ and $\cos{(\Delta t)}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

**The Problem**

I am modelling a continuous distribution using an infinite sum of individual elements and I need to prove that the model is equivalent to the known (i.e. accepted in the literature) continuous function.

The sum is

$$
\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi}} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \sqrt{\frac{1}{j \Delta t}} (\cos{(\theta(t - j \Delta t - \Delta t))} - \cos{(\theta(t - j \Delta t + \Delta t))})
$$

and the known continuous function is

$$
\sqrt{\frac{\theta}{2}} (\cos{(\theta t)} - \sin{(\theta t)})
$$

My derivation of the sum has been checked by a third party and the same equation was independently derived by another third party, so I am reasonably sure that the maths up to this point is correct.

**What I tried so far**

I tried to turn the sum into an integral but I don't know how to evaluate the resulting terms $\sqrt{\frac{1}{dt}}$ and $\cos{(dt)}$.

I also tried looking at just a single term (i.e. $n=1$) in the sum and trying to equate the derivative of this to the derivative of the known function but I got stuck here

$$
\sin{(\theta (t + \Delta t))} - \sin{(\theta (t - \Delta t))} = \sqrt{2 \theta \pi \Delta t}(\sin{(\theta t)} + \cos{(\theta t)})
$$

Since I couldn't solve it analytically, I checked convergence numerically using MatLab and it does indeed appear to converge to the known continuous function.

[Picture of numerical model convergence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g08x4.png)

**My question**

Does anyone know how to overcome the $\sqrt{\frac{1}{dt}}$ and $\cos{(dt)}$ problems? Either how to evaluate them or another approach to prove equivalence?

*Notes*

(1)In case anyone is wondering where these odd terms came from, the $\Delta t$ is the timestep length. The square root term comes from a speed equation and the two cosine terms come from a magnitude equation, which is calculated as the difference of a value that is found using $\cos{t}$.

(2) I posted my first attempt at a proof and the final proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4072325/can-i-treat-delta-t-in-different-ways-when-lim-delta-t-to-0-i-e-de), in which I used a slightly different version of the sum and continuous function, so I have edited the sum and continuous function here to be consistent. I have copied the proof here so there is no need to follow the link unless you want to see my mathematical errors :)

Comment: As a rule of thumb, I would start by replacing $\cos(x)$ with $\frac{1}{2}(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})$ then seeing if I had some variant of a geometric sequence.

Comment: You're dealing with stochastic differential equations, right?

Comment: @Paul thank you for the suggestion, I will have a go with that approach.

Comment: @Aruralreader I don't believe so - the physical scenario on which the problem is based is deterministic.

Comment: Thank you @Anjali. If you get a chance I'd be interested in seeing the derivation leading to this, a reference somewhere? Good luck to you!

Comment: @Aruralreader Thank you :) I'd be happy to share it but am not sure what is the best way? It's currently in a Word Doc on my OneDrive.

Comment: @Anjali. I guess the only place I've seen things like $\sqrt{\Delta t}$ is in diffusion processes modeled as random walks, where you end up assuming a discretization in space and time, $\Delta x$ and $\Delta t$ respectively, shrinking in a way such that $(\Delta x)^2/\Delta t = 2 D$ with some constant $D$.

Comment: @Paul I think I may have managed it with your suggestion, only I ended up with polylogarithms instead of geometric sums. I'm waiting on confirmation!

Comment: @Aruralreader It actually is a model of diffusion! It's based on a much simplified problem so that it's analytically solvable.

Comment: Wonder if you could call the sum y then differentiating twice you get $y'' = -{\theta}^2y$ and are left with the problem of calculating $y(0)$ and $y'(0)$. Would involve a lot of hand waving at infinite sums and limits though!

Comment: Might it also be allowed to put $\Delta {t} = \frac{2\pi}{N}$ then let N go to infinity? This should simplify the infinite sum (I think).

Comment: @Paul Sorry, I don't quite understand - why would we differentiate with respect to $\theta$? The polylogarithm sums here are convergent and solvable for $\lim_{\Delta t \to 0}$. Doing so combines $\sqrt{\Delta t}$ and $\cos{(\Delta t)}$ into $\frac{1}{\Delta t}$ so I converted that to $\frac{1}{d t}$ (this is the step I am not sure is allowed) and differentiated, which gave me exactly the same equation as the known continuous function.

Comment: I was thinking differentiate with respect to t. Glad to see you have it done though!

Comment: @Paul Oh of course, I confused myself, sorry. I am not sure about the final step I did converting $\frac{1}{\Delta t}$ to $\frac{1}{d t}$ (or indeed if I made any other non-allowable steps) but I will update here as soon as my work gets checked. Thank you so much for the suggestion - I'll now remember to convert to exponential as a rule of thumb going forward!

Answer (score 1):

@Paul's suggestion of converting to complex notation was key for me, as it makes manipulation of the problem so much easier! I was able to identify the summation as being two polylogarithm functions, both of which are convergent. Then I got stuck but, on the suggestion of a colleague, I used the Taylor Expansion to eliminate $\Delta t$.

We can rewrite the sum as

$$
\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{\frac{1}{\pi}}\frac{(e^{i \theta \Delta t} - e^{-i \theta \Delta t})}{\Delta t}(e^{-i \theta t} \sqrt{\Delta t} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{(e^{i \theta \Delta t})^j}{j^{\frac{1}{2}}} - e^{i \theta t} \sqrt{\Delta t} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{(e^{-i \theta \Delta t})^j}{j^{\frac{1}{2}}})
$$

where the summations terms are polylogarithms.

Now we use the following limits. The first is derived from the Taylor Expansion and the second and third are derived from the polylogarithm function.

$$
\lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \frac{(e^{i \theta \Delta t} - e^{-i \theta \Delta t})}{\Delta t} = 2 i \theta
$$

$$
\lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \sqrt{\Delta t} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{(e^{i \theta \Delta t})^j}{j^{\frac{1}{2}}} = \sqrt{\frac{i \pi}{\theta}}
$$

$$
\lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \sqrt{\Delta t} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{(e^{-i \theta \Delta t})^j}{j^{\frac{1}{2}}} = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{i \theta}}
$$

This yields

$$
\frac{\sqrt{\theta}}{2}i(e^{i \theta t} \sqrt{i} - e^{i \theta t} \sqrt{-1})
$$

Finally we convert back to trignometric form using $ i(e^{i \theta t} \sqrt{i} - e^{i \theta t} \sqrt{-1}) = \sqrt{2}(\sin{(\theta t)} - \cos{(\theta t))} $ to give

$$
\sqrt{\frac{\theta}{2}}(\sin{(\theta t)} - \cos{(\theta t}))
$$

**However, note that this is NOT the same as the analytical solution; the sign is reversed.** It appears that I missed a negative sign somewhere when deriving the original sum.

*Thanks to @Karl and @Bannach for their critique of my first proof attempt.*