# Can I treat $\Delta t$ in different ways when $\lim_{\Delta t \to 0}$? i.e. $\Delta t = 0$ in one section and $\Delta t = d t$ in another?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification, exponential-sum

**The Problem**

*Note: This is a possible solution to a question I asked a short time ago.*

I am trying to prove that this sum

$$
\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi}} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \sqrt{\frac{1}{j \Delta t}} (\cos{(\theta(t - j \Delta t - \Delta t))} - \cos{(\theta(t - j \Delta t + \Delta t))})$$

is exactly equivalent to this continuous function as $\lim_{\Delta t \to 0}$

$$
\sqrt{\frac{\theta}{2}} (\cos{(\theta t)} - \sin{(\theta t)})
$$

**My Proof**

I converted to complex notation and rearranged to get two sums, each of which is a polylogarithm function

$$
\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{\frac{1}{\pi \Delta t}}(e^{i \theta \Delta t} + e^{-i \theta \Delta t}) (e^{-i \theta \Delta t} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{(e^{i \theta \Delta t})^j}{j^{\frac{1}{2}}} - e^{i \theta \Delta t} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{(e^{-i \theta \Delta t})^j}{j^{\frac{1}{2}}})
$$

Both sums are solvable when $\lim_{\Delta t \to 0}$ (since the power term in the denominator is $<1$), giving the following

$$
\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{\frac{1}{\pi \Delta t}}(e^{i \theta \Delta t} + e^{-i \theta \Delta t})(e^{-i \theta t} \sqrt{\frac{i \pi}{\theta \Delta t}} - e^{i \theta t} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{i \theta \Delta t}})
$$

And simplifying this gives

$$
\frac{1}{4 \Delta t}\sqrt{\frac{1}{\theta}}(e^{i \theta \Delta t} + e^{-i \theta \Delta t})(e^{-i \theta t} \sqrt{i} - e^{i \theta t} \sqrt{-i})
$$

**The Question**

To solve this, is it acceptable to *simultaneously* let $\Delta t = d t$ in the fraction *and* let $\Delta t = 0$ in the exponents? i.e. to yield

$$
\frac{1}{2 d t}\sqrt{\frac{1}{\theta}}(e^{-i \theta t} \sqrt{i} - e^{i \theta t} \sqrt{-i})
$$

so that I can then differentiate?

If so, using $e^{-i \theta t} \sqrt{i} + e^{i \theta t} \sqrt{-i} = \sqrt{2}(\sin(\theta t) + \cos{\theta t})$ to convert back to real numbers and then differentiating yields the continuous function above.

Comment: By "exactly equivalent to..." do you mean "is the limit as $\Delta t\to 0$ of ... "?

Comment: And a more relevant mathematical question: how do you get to differentiation? There is no $d$ in the numerator, so to say. As $\Delta t\to 0$, your expression simply diverges to Infinity.

Comment: That being said, I haven't checked your prior algebra or polylogarithm asymptotics

Comment: In general it's not valid to let different instances of a variable "reach the limit at different times". For example, $\lim_{x\to0}\frac xx=1$ whereas $\lim_{x\to0}\frac0x=0$.

Comment: @Bananach Thanks for your comments. Yes, I meant as $\lim_{\Delta t \to 0}$ - thanks, I have edited the question. My reasoning for differentiating was that if for some quantity $Q$, $Q = \frac{1}{2 d t}\sqrt{\frac{1}{\theta}}(e^{-i \theta t} \sqrt{i} + e^{i \theta t} \sqrt{-i})$, then $\int Q dt = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{\theta}}(e^{-i \theta t} \sqrt{i} + e^{i \theta t} \sqrt{-i})$ so it is logical that to get $Q$, I would differentiate with respect to $t$. I am not sure if this logic is mathematically correct though.

Comment: @Bananach Also, I am (almost) certain that the solution is finite because I checked the sum numerically and it appears to converge to the continuous function. However, I don't know what maths to use to prove it. Any suggestions would are much appreciated!

Comment: Thank you @Karl. That is exactly what I was wondering. Would you say that this proof is therefore invalid? And do you have any suggestions on what approach I could take instead?

Comment: Your symbolic manipulations are wrong. Where does the integral sign go? You would be right to say that $Qdt = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{\theta}}(e^{-i\theta t }\sqrt{i}+e^{i\theta t}\sqrt{-i})$ but $\int Qdt $ is therefore undefined! In fact, you can easily see that as $\Delta t\to 0$, your $Q$ diverges to infinity since it is the product of $\frac{1}{2\Delta t}\to\infty$ and something that doesn't depend on $\Delta t$

Answer (score 1):

As @Karl pointed out, it is not acceptable to let different instances of a variable "reach the limit at different times". On the suggestion of a colleague, I used the Taylor Expansion for $e^{i \theta \Delta t}+e^{-i \theta \Delta t}$ to remedy this error.

We can rewrite the sum as

$$
\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{\frac{1}{\pi}}\frac{(e^{i \theta \Delta t} - e^{-i \theta \Delta t})}{\Delta t}(e^{-i \theta t} \sqrt{\Delta t} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{(e^{i \theta \Delta t})^j}{j^{\frac{1}{2}}} - e^{i \theta t} \sqrt{\Delta t} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{(e^{-i \theta \Delta t})^j}{j^{\frac{1}{2}}})
$$

Now we use the following limits (where the summation terms are polylogarithms)

$$
\lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \frac{(e^{i \theta \Delta t} - e^{-i \theta \Delta t})}{\Delta t} = 2 i \theta
$$

$$
\lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \sqrt{\Delta t} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{(e^{i \theta \Delta t})^j}{j^{\frac{1}{2}}} = \sqrt{\frac{i \pi}{\theta}}
$$

$$
\lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \sqrt{\Delta t} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{(e^{-i \theta \Delta t})^j}{j^{\frac{1}{2}}} = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{i \theta}}
$$

to derive

$$
\frac{\sqrt{\theta}}{2}i(e^{i \theta t} \sqrt{i} - e^{i \theta t} \sqrt{-1})
$$

Finally we convert back to trignometric form using $ i(e^{i \theta t} \sqrt{i} - e^{i \theta t} \sqrt{-1}) = \sqrt{2}(\sin{(\theta t)} - \cos{(\theta t))} $ to give

$$
\sqrt{\frac{\theta}{2}}(\sin{(\theta t)} - \cos{(\theta t}))
$$

**However, note that this is NOT the same as the analytical solution; the sign is reversed.** It appears that I missed a negative sign somewhere when deriving the original sum.

*Thanks to @Karl and @Bannach for their critique of the original question.*